# Show that a topology is a first countable space

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\tau$ be the topology on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the closed open intervals $[a,b)$. Show that it is a first countable space.

So, what I think I have to do is to show that for any point $p \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a countable local base, for example $$B_{p}= \left\{\left[p,n^{-1} \right)\; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

My reasoning is that the open spheres in this topology are the same close open intervals and that the open sphere is getting smaller as $n$ increases and all of those balls include $p$. Am i correct?

Comment: Almost there. You're morally correct. We just replace the usual $(p-1/n,p+1/n)$ by $[p,p+1/n)$.

Comment: Thank you, i got it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s not going to work unless $p=0$. If $p\ge 1$, the sets $\left[p,\frac1n\right)$ are all empty. However, you could let

$$\mathscr{B}_p=\left\{\left[p,p+\frac1n\right):n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\,.$$

To prove that this is a local base at $p$ you must show that if $U$ is any open nbhd of $p$ in this topology, there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $p\in\left[p,p+\frac1n\right)\subseteq U$. You can start by observing that the sets of the form $[a,b)$ with $a<b$ are a base for the topology, so if $U$ is an open nbhd of $p$, there must be $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that $p\in[a,b)\subseteq U$. Now you just have to explain why there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that

$$\left[p,p+\frac1n\right)\subseteq[a,b)\,.$$